# Inserting object in ascending order in Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

What I'm trying to do is insert objects into a linked list in ascending order using the first parameter in the class constructor, char*. The code I have presently does not show any error, but the order isn't right.

So far, I have this piece of code below

```
void list::insert(Obj* NObj)
{
    if (head == NULL)
        head = NObj;
    else if (strcmp(NObj->name, head->name) < 0 ))
    {
        NObj->next = head;
        head = NObj;
    }
    else
    {
        Obj * t1 = head;
        Obj * t2 = t1->next;
        while ((t2 != NULL) && strcmp(NObj->name, head->name) < 0 )
        {
            t1 = t2;
            t2 = t2->next;
        }
        NObj->next = t2;
        t1->next = NObj;
    }
}
```

When I insert using the following objects

```
Obj("Brit", 6));
Obj("Germ", 2));
Obj("Cana", 7));
Obj("Zimb", 9));
Obj("Jama", 1));
```

I get the following from my Print function

```
 Jama
 Germ
 Zimb
 Cana
 Brit
```

Instead of

```
 Brit
 Cana
 Germ
 Jama
 Zimb
```

Note:
The name parameter I'm inserting by is a char*

Comment: What is `name` ? Show full structure of your code.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Name is a `char*` from Obj class constructor.

Comment: Used strcmp to compare values, but still same.

Comment: `while ((t2 != NULL) && strcmp(NObj->name, head->name) < 0 )` - you want to move down the list while strcmp >= 0, and you want to compare to t1 instead of head.

Comment: @sje397 I still get the same results.

Comment: @hello `The code I have presently does not show any error,`  The code is not working properly, so there is an error.  Second, show a complete program.  `When I insert using the following objects`  Your interface to `insert` takes pointers not objects.  You need to show the actual code you are using.  Better yet a complete, but small program that demonstrates the error.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This question was based as a follow up to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130366/linked-list-class-not-inserting-nodes-when-called-from-another-class-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has the conditional:

```
head->name >= Nobj->name
```

This compares two variables of type `char *`, which compares the two objects by the location of the string, not the contents of the string.

Instead, use `std::string` or `strcmp()`.

I'm also concerned that you are not properly taking ownership of `name` in your `Obj` constructor, but you haven't shown any code for that...

Comment: Please explain what you mean by `name` not taking proper ownership in `Obj`

Comment: Or use `std::lexicographical_compare`

Comment: @hello Who created the node?  If it is the user of the linked list, that is a poor interface.  The user of the link list shouldn't be creating the node or even know about `node`.   A proper interface would have `insert` passed the data to insert, not `node`.  That is probably what the "ownership" comment is referring to.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `Obj` is from a different class. I'm only passing its object  `NObj` to the Linked List method.

Comment: @hello See my comment above.  You are passing pointers, not objects.  So there is more than what you're showing us that could be causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess another error is in this clause:

```
strcmp (NObj->name, head->name)
```

which is in the loop started by:

```
while ((t2 != NULL) && strcmp(NObj->name, head->name) < 0 )
                                                ^^^^  ^^^
```

I was expecting your code to compare the new object to t2->name(), trying to find the location before which you would insert the new object.

I think I am suggesting

```
while ((t2 != NULL) && strcmp(NObj->name, head->t2) < 0 )
```